# How can fix json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

Here is my script:

```py
from requests import get
x = get("https://stackoverflow.com/").json()
```

Here is the full error I get:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I expect it to get the HTML code of StackOverflow's home page in JSON format, but I get this error. How would I fix this?

Comment: What are you attempting to do? Why do you want the *HTML code of StackOverflow's home page in JSON format*?

Comment: However do you think HTML could be converted to JSON ?!?!?

Answer (score 2):

Doing a `GET` request on a URL endpoint may return any type of data. The data being returned can be identified by the `Content-type` header that's returned.

You can (and should) use the `.json()` method only if the `Content-type` is `application/json`.

For convenience sake, let's see what curl gives (you can see what requests gives, by using `hdrs = request.get("...").headers`)

```
$ curl -I https://stackoverflow.com
HTTP/2 200 
cache-control: private
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-request-guid: 7d871e80-a0b1-4f70-96d1-5022c8b08ada
strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000
feature-policy: microphone 'none'; speaker 'none'
content-security-policy: upgrade-insecure-requests; frame-ancestors 'self' https://stackexchange.com
accept-ranges: bytes
date: Thu, 19 Mar 2020 06:35:54 GMT
via: 1.1 varnish
x-served-by: cache-ams21083-AMS
x-cache: MISS
x-cache-hits: 0
x-timer: S1584599754.957920,VS0,VE88
vary: Fastly-SSL
x-dns-prefetch-control: off
set-cookie: prov=ffb66caf-2ce3-8b67-5cf0-d0ec734e9d3e; domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
content-length: 112411
```

You see that `Content-type` is `text/html` and thus the `.json()` method is failing.

- Now, if you want to convert a HTML to JSON, you need to define your won methods to do so. HTML is a markup language, it is not used to transfer data across endpoints (unlike XML).
- Maybe you might want to parse the HTML response, in which case, `BeautifulSoup4` is a good Python Module to get started with.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
resp= requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com/")
resp_dict = json.loads(resp.text)
print(resp_dict)
```